# Fatal error when running any micronaut CLI command

Tags: java, groovy, micronaut

I am trying to create a micronaut application using the micronaut CLI, however every `mn` command I run results in the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :4:10: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
| Error Error occurred running Micronaut CLI: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

This error is ubiquitous. So long as I as much as type `mn` in my shell, the error is produced. From what I've gathered, this error can be found when using Groovy's XmlSlurper, so this seems to be an error produced by some internal configuration in the CLI tool. As a result, adding the suggested `--stacktrace` option does nothing, since it should be on the internal call, not the one I do to `mn`. I can't seem to find a way to configure the "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" setting manually.

This error occurs no matter which version of the micronaut CLI I'm using.

Comment: What is the Java version? Micronaut version?  mn command ?

Comment: Java is graal 19.2.0 packaged 1.8.0_222, the rest are answered in the question itself; any micronaut version, and any mn command.

Comment: Ben, it's better to solve exact one problem then "nothing works" problem. Please edit your question and provide: exact version of each component (jvm, micronaut), exact command, and error message including full stacktrace. Then maybe somebody will help you.

Comment: Certainly, but this question is wholly specific in that regard. There's a Java version, followed by the fact that *literally* all versions of Micronaut, and literally *all* `mn` commands result in *that exact error*. There is no full stacktrace. There is no way for me to get a full stacktrace without recompiling Micronaut myself. This is all I have to work with, which is why I came here for help in the first place, to see if anyone had the same issue and found a solution.

Comment: search to any xml files containing `DOCTYPE` and try to remove it.

Comment: It isn't clear why Groovy's XmlSlurper would be involved.  I can't reproduce the issue.  http://jeffscreencasts.s3.amazonaws.com/benasks.mp4 demonstrates what I am seeing on macOs.